# Taking specific 2d array from 3d in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Is there a way to avoid using the for loop and get the result just by calling arr with some indexing? Potentially dim1 will be equal to 50 000, dim2 up to 1000, dim3 fixed to 3.

```
import numpy as np
dim1 = 10
dim2 = 2
dim3 = 3
arr = np.arange(60).reshape(dim1,dim2,dim3)
arr2 = np.arange(dim1*dim2).reshape(dim1,dim2)
np.mod(arr2,dim3,out=arr2)

res = []
rng = np.arange(dim1)
for x in range(dim2):
    sl = arr2[:,x]
    temp = arr[rng,x,sl]
    res.append(temp)
res = np.asarray(res).T
```

Basically, I would like to extract the values from arr which is a 3D array, however the matrix arr2 indicates which columns to select.

Best

Comment: What about `arr[:, :, x]`?

Comment: Try `arr[(*np.ogrid[:dim1, :dim2], arr2)]`

Comment: @PaulPanzer Seems to work on this simple example. I will test it tomorrow on real data as well. Thanks a lot!